# Работать с фалами на телефоне через c#

Tags: c#, android

Подключаем телефон по usb. Как через c# программой можно сделать что-то вроде проводника windows, чтобы можно было переходить по папкам и к примеру открыть фотографию.
Я пробовал работь как с диском, проблема в том, что путь до телефона This PC\Redmi Note 7 и как к такому пути обратиться я не знаю.

Comment: Это обычный путь, ничем не отличается от всех других.

Comment: Ага, понял. В Проводнике Виндоус нажмите на строку адреса - увидите настоящий путь.

Comment: This PC\Redmi Note 7\Internal shared storage - вот путь, а как по такому пути обратиться в c# - да даже бонально как черезcmd перейти туда